# I don't know how to do the same thing pull, create and start instead of docker run -dti

Tags: docker

Using an image from https://hub.docker.com/_/php.

## Create and launch a hogehoge-php container with docker run -dti

```
% docker run -dti --name hogehoge-php php
```

Then I can see that the `hogehoge-php` container is up and running.

confirmed:

```
% docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
2c9e7ff1a952 php "docker-php-entrypoi..." 6 seconds ago Up 5 seconds ago hogehoge-php
```

## try with pull, create and start

I read that the `docker run` is a command that performs `docker pull`, `docker create`, and `docker start` all at once. So I decided to try it out as follows (I didn't do the `docker pull` because I already have a local php image).

```
% docker create --name foofoo-php php
c7687c088dda9b71d9380e9ca472afa436ac63785c1d2c195b8a08147f8adec9
% docker start foofoo-php
foofoo-php
% docker ps -a                           
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
c7687c088dda php "docker-php-entrypoi..." 16 seconds ago Exited (0) 3 seconds ago foofoo-php
```

When I tried as above, I got `Exited (0) 3 seconds ago`, and the `foofoo-php` container created by `docker create` doesn't stand up all the time.

The `foofoo-php` container made by `docker create` doesn't stand up(options not available).

```
% docker start -dti foofoo-php
unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -dti
See 'docker start --help'.
```

The `i` option is available, and I was able to run it, but it doesn't leave the docker running.

```
% docker start -i foofoo-php
Interactive shell

% docker ps -a                
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
c7687c088dda php "docker-php-entrypoi..." 3 minutes ago Exited (0) 5 seconds ago foofoo-php
```

**How can I `create` and `start` instead of `run -dti`?**

## By the way, I tried docker run without -dti

By the way, I tried `docker run` without `-dti`.

```
% docker run --name barbarbar-php php
Interactive shell

% docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
6215c71a13a4 php "docker-php-entrypoi..." 15 seconds ago Exited (0) 15 seconds ago barbar-php
```

The container was created, but it's not standing up. I thought I should try `docker start`:

```
% docker start barbar-php
barbar-php
% docker ps -a                    
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
6215c71a13a4        php                 "docker-php-entrypoi…"   33 seconds ago      Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                        barbar-php
```

but the container doesn't start up.

## On the other hand, stop and start a container created by docker run -dti

On the other hand, try to `stop` and `start` a container created by `docker run -dti`, it running up after start.

```
% docker stop hogehoge-php
hogehoge-php
% docker start hogehoge-php
hogehoge-php
% docker ps -a             
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
6215c71a13a4        php                 "docker-php-entrypoi…"   4 minutes ago       Exited (0) About a minute ago                       barbar-php
c7687c088dda        php                 "docker-php-entrypoi…"   11 minutes ago      Exited (0) 8 minutes ago                            foofoo-php
2c9e7ff1a952        php                 "docker-php-entrypoi…"   14 minutes ago      Up 2 seconds                                        hogehoge-php <----- Here
```

## Behavior Summary

- docker run

  - with dit option

    - up after a run
    - up after start
  - without dit option

    - not up after a run
    - not up after a start
- docker create

  - not up after a run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is a `docker create -t` to allocate a pseudo-TTY for you container.

Since the entrypoint for the image you are running is a php shell running at the foreground, the container, when started, figures out that it doesn't have a tty to attach to an exit with 0.

```
docker pull php
docker create -t --name hogehoge-php php
docker start hogehoge-php
```